# Смена изображения кнопки вкл/выкл звука фонового видео

Tags: javascript, html, css

Уважаемые Господа. Собственно функционал выполняется. Не могу заставить кнопку при выключении и включении звука менять изображение кнопки. Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

```js
function mute(btn, elem) {
  var video = document.getElementById(elem);
  if (video.muted) {
    video.muted = false;
  } else {
    video.muted = true;
  }
}
```

```css
#sounds {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 101;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  top: 46px;
  left: -2px;
}

.btn_001 {
  //Задание общего стиля для кнопки
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  background: lime url(../img/img_473b.png) no-repeat top center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn_001:hover {
  //Стиль кнопки при новедении на него курсора
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: none;
  background: red url(../img/img_473b2.png) no-repeat top center;
}

.btn_001:focus {
  //Стиль кнопки, когда она в фокусе
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: none;
  background: red url(../img/img_473b2.png) no-repeat top center;
}

.btn_001:active {
  //Стиль кнопки при нажатии
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: none;
  background: lime url(../img/img_473b.png) no-repeat top center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="in">
  <video id="myVideo" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay loop>
<source src="img/video/zastavka_1.mp4"></source>
<source src="img/video/zastavka.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
</video>
</div>

<div id="sounds">
  <button onclick="mute(this, 'myVideo')" class="btn_001"><img src="img/img_473b.png"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: а где звук??????

Comment: Вы понимаете, видео достаточно большое. Я так понял по условиям форума его грузить не стоит. собственно звук включается и выключается, только изображение самой кнопки не меняется по человечески. Если надо, я попробую загрузить видео.. Т.е., сейчас она зеленая. Наводим курсор - становится красной. нажимаем она должна остаться красной. Теперь решили включить. Процесс должен быть в обратную сторону, Со звуком так и происходит, но вот с изображением - никак.

Answer (score 0):

> Не могу заставить кнопку при выключении и включении звука менять изображение кнопки

не вижу я где вы пытаетесь менять изображение

> Подскажите пожалуйста

т.к. картинку внутри батона - всё очень просто

```
var img = btn.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
img.src = ''
```